# Use interface to convert collection of objects with extensions and lambdas

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, extension-methods, generics

I have some objects like user, address and so on, and Im converting them to business objects using extension methods:

```
public static UserModel ToPresentationForm(this User pUser)
    {
        return new UserModel
        {
          ...
          map data
          ...
        };
    }
```

Also I need to convert strongly typed collections and usually I have the following code:

```
public static List<UserModel> ToPresentationForm(this List<User> pUserColl)
    {
        return pUserColl.Select(x => x.ToPresentationForm()).ToList();
    }
```

I was thinking, what if I add some interface, like IPresentationForms and will be able to use it, to write method like

```
public static List<T> ToPresentationForm(this List<IPresentationForms> pTemplate)
    {
        return pUserColl.Select(x => x.ToPresentationForm()).ToList();
    }
```

Not sure how to provide parameter to method type to make it generic. So the actual question is, how to do that.

P.S. Im using C# 4.0

Comment: in your last example, you have `.Select(x => x.ToPresentationForm())`.  What are you expecting `.ToPresentationForm` to invoke?  Are you expecting something dynamic to happen such that it invokes the correct extentsion method that you've made for the given concrete type?

Comment: Actually yes, from example you can see that actually all I do to convert collection is copypasting the same code, just specifying the type. So I thought maybe there`s a way to specify type in some other way.

Comment: and what is `T`?  Why is the method named `ToPresentationForm` but it takes a list of `IPresentationForm` -- that seems to make no sense.

Comment: Kirk, it`s not a code that will work. I just posted how it`s done with 2 methods for now. And every new type needs 2 methods, one of which is almost same for all types. So the question is how to make it generic. My code example is piece of code that is not working, and I just put it to show what I`d like to have in the end (one method that will convert collection for all types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately since there is likely no relationship between `User` and `UserModel`, there is no way to create an interface to do what you want.

On the other hand, let's say that `User` and `UserModel` both implement the `IUser` interface. Then you could have an interface like this:

```
interface IPresentationForms<T>
{
    T ToPresentationForm();
}
```

And you could define `User` like this:

```
class User: IUser, IPresentationForms<IUser>
{
    public IUser ToPresentationForm()
    {
        return new UserModel(...);
    }
    .... // implement IUser
}
```

That could enable you to define `ToPresentationForm` something like this:

```
public static List<T> ToPresentationForm<T>(this IEnumerable<T> pTemplate)
    where T : IPresentationForms<T>
{    
    return pTemplate.Select(x => x.ToPresentationForm()).ToList();    
}
```

That's a lot of work to do to avoid a few extra methods.

Comment: What do you mean by no interface between 2 classes?

Comment: Since your definition of `UserModel` likely doesn't mention `User` anywhere, you cannot do what you want. If `UserModel` implemented `IModel<User>` (for example), maybe you could make your interface.

Comment: Ok, what and should be implemented to make it convert all collections with one method? :-). I don`t mind to vary things a little bit, just I think as how it works now it`s not good as I`m doing copypaste, just to specify type.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy fix here. If you post the declarations of `User` and `UserModel` maybe we can see if this is possible, but it likely isn't.

Comment: actually it`s 2 classes with identical list of properties. Let it be FirstName and LastName for example.